# Spring Boot + JPA[Hibernate backed] + mysql = Data truncation: Data too long for column 'ATTRIBUTE_NAME' at row 1

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

The error is occurring when trying to run an insert statement against a mysql db. I have turned on the sql args trace for hibernate to see exactly what the action translates to query as well as the bindings.

In the mysql db the column ATTRIBUTE_NAME is VARCHAR(200)...looking at the traced logs I see the string is 79 characters("org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN").

Below are the logs - please point me in the correct direction as this does confuse me quite a bit. Look for "SQL Error: 1406, SQLState: 22001" and read entry before that.

```
    The attr: org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN
 and the length: 79
The attr: SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
 and the length: 23
2019-02-07 09:07:50.761 DEBUG 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select CODE_NAMEse0_.id as id1_16_, CODE_NAMEse0_.EXPIRY_DATE as EXPIRY_D2_16_, CODE_NAMEse0_.INACTIVE_INTERVAL_MIN as INACTIVE3_16_, CODE_NAMEse0_.SESSION_TYPE as SESSION_4_16_, CODE_NAMEse0_.SESSION_ID as SESSION_5_16_, CODE_NAMEse0_.START_DATE as START_DA6_16_, CODE_NAMEse0_.username as username7_16_ from CODE_NAME_SESSION CODE_NAMEse0_ where CODE_NAMEse0_.username=?
2019-02-07 09:07:50.761 TRACE 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [0835623872]
2019-02-07 09:07:50.770 TRACE 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_16_] : [BIGINT]) - [474]
2019-02-07 09:07:50.770 TRACE 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([EXPIRY_D2_16_] : [TIMESTAMP]) - [2019-02-07 09:11:40.0]
2019-02-07 09:07:50.770 TRACE 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([INACTIVE3_16_] : [BIGINT]) - [5]
2019-02-07 09:07:50.771 TRACE 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([SESSION_5_16_] : [VARCHAR]) - [67898350-7858-4de1-8e45-e6545768b875]
2019-02-07 09:07:50.771 TRACE 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([START_DA6_16_] : [TIMESTAMP]) - [2019-02-07 09:06:40.0]
2019-02-07 09:07:50.771 TRACE 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([username7_16_] : [VARCHAR]) - [0835623872]
2019-02-07 09:07:50.771 DEBUG 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select CODE_NAMEse0_.CODE_NAME_SESSION_ID as CODE_NAME4_17_0_, CODE_NAMEse0_.id as id1_17_0_, CODE_NAMEse0_.id as id1_17_1_, CODE_NAMEse0_.ATTRIBUTE_NAME as ATTRIBUT2_17_1_, CODE_NAMEse0_.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE as ATTRIBUT3_17_1_, CODE_NAMEse0_.CODE_NAME_SESSION_ID as CODE_NAME4_17_1_ from CODE_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE CODE_NAMEse0_ where CODE_NAMEse0_.CODE_NAME_SESSION_ID=?
2019-02-07 09:07:50.771 TRACE 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [474]
2019-02-07 09:07:50.773 TRACE 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_17_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [1410]
2019-02-07 09:07:50.774 TRACE 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([ATTRIBUT2_17_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT]
2019-02-07 09:07:50.776 TRACE 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([ATTRIBUT3_17_1_] : [VARBINARY]) - [org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@2ec961af: Authentication: za.co.intellimali.CODE_NAME.security.AuthenticationToken@2ec961af: Principal: za.co.intellimali.CODE_NAME.domain.CODE_NAMESession@7552b3f3; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_MEAL, ROLE_ACCOM, ROLE_STU, MEMBER]
2019-02-07 09:07:50.776 TRACE 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([CODE_NAME4_17_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [474]
2019-02-07 09:07:50.776 TRACE 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([CODE_NAME4_17_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [474]
2019-02-07 09:07:50.777 TRACE 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_17_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [1410]
2019-02-07 09:07:50.780 DEBUG 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into CODE_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE (ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_VALUE, CODE_NAME_SESSION_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
2019-02-07 09:07:50.780 TRACE 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN]
2019-02-07 09:07:50.780 TRACE 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARBINARY] - [org.springframework.security.web.csrf.DefaultCsrfToken@6f0adee5]
2019-02-07 09:07:50.780 TRACE 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [474]
2019-02-07 09:07:50.791  WARN 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1406, SQLState: 22001
2019-02-07 09:07:50.792 ERROR 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Data truncation: Data too long for column 'ATTRIBUTE_NAME' at row 1
2019-02-07 09:07:50.805 DEBUG 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select CODE_NAMEse0_.id as id1_16_, CODE_NAMEse0_.EXPIRY_DATE as EXPIRY_D2_16_, CODE_NAMEse0_.INACTIVE_INTERVAL_MIN as INACTIVE3_16_, CODE_NAMEse0_.SESSION_TYPE as SESSION_4_16_, CODE_NAMEse0_.SESSION_ID as SESSION_5_16_, CODE_NAMEse0_.START_DATE as START_DA6_16_, CODE_NAMEse0_.username as username7_16_ from CODE_NAME_SESSION CODE_NAMEse0_ where CODE_NAMEse0_.SESSION_ID=?
2019-02-07 09:07:50.806 TRACE 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [67898350-7858-4de1-8e45-e6545768b875]
2019-02-07 09:07:50.807 TRACE 18764 --- [nio-8998-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_16_] : [BIGINT]) - [474]
```

The table:
[image: The table in question]

The variable in question on java side:

```
@Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_NAME")
private String attributeName;
```

I have to be missing something obvious...

EDIT: what I pick up from wireshark

```
    insert into CODE_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE (ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_VALUE, CODE_NAME_SESSION_ID) 
values 
(
    'org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN'
    , _binary'..\0.sr\06org.springframework.security.web.csrf.DefaultCsrfTokenZ.../....\0.L\0\nheaderNamet\0.Ljava/lang/String;L\0\rparameterNameq\0~\0.L\0.tokenq\0~\0.xpt\0.X-CSRF-TOKENt\0._csrft\0$04735f03-57cf-4984-860c-e8e03400d432'
    , 474);
    ....~.#22001Data too long for column 'ATTRIBUTE_NAME' at row 1  ....rollback................SET autocommit=1................SET autocommit=0................commit................SET autocommit=1................SET autocommit=0................select CODE_NAMEse0_.id as id1_16_, CODE_NAMEse0_.EXPIRY_DATE as EXPIRY_D2_16_, CODE_NAMEse0_.INACTIVE_INTERVAL_MIN as INACTIVE3_16_, CODE_NAMEse0_.SESSION_TYPE as SESSION_4_16_, CODE_NAMEse0_.SESSION_ID as SESSION_5_16_, CODE_NAMEse0_.START_DATE as START_DA6_16_, CODE_NAMEse0_.username as username7_16_ from CODE_NAME_SESSION CODE_NAMEse0_ where CODE_NAMEse0_.SESSION_ID='36c6cb34-aa46-4821-b3a4-15e80c7c57fa'
```

The above when run in mysql workbench will run with a warning and truncate the ATTRIBUTE_NAME to 'org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionC'

if I run:

```
    insert into CODE_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE (ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_VALUE, CODE_NAME_SESSION_ID) 
values 
(
    'CSRF_TOKEN'
    , _binary'..\0.sr\06org.springframework.security.web.csrf.DefaultCsrfTokenZ.../....\0.L\0\nheaderNamet\0.Ljava/lang/String;L\0\rparameterNameq\0~\0.L\0.tokenq\0~\0.xpt\0.X-CSRF-TOKENt\0._csrft\0$04735f03-57cf-4984-860c-e8e03400d432'
    , 474);
```

Works without warning showing that the table is not taking bigger lengths for ATTRIBUTE_NAME. I feel this is now a mysql problem and not java + spring + jpa

Comment: can you share the code which insert data in DB

Comment: entitymanager.persist()

Comment: and entityManager.merge() when dealing with detached due to serialization

Comment: Paste actual exception, paste set and persist code.

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE youtTableName` in SQL console and paste the output. Did you change varchar limit in sql workbench and forgot to apply changes?

Comment: will check now Antoniosss...one sec - sorry for being a lil slow on replies

Comment: Your response implies that you in fact DID change the limit.

Comment: Yes you are correct - this is what happened...Originally using the spring session used their script which created a table called SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE...now we changed this table but on dev we still have it as a copy(should remove it). Out of habit I change the value there and committed when the table I was suppose to change was not that one at all but our custom table. 
Really sorry guys and thank you

Comment: Are you looking at the right table? The names in the screenshot don't match those in the query.

Comment: Yes it was the incorrect table but do not know how to mark this as solved. So I delete this post?

Answer (score 0):

Antoniosss's Query: SHOW CREATE TABLE youtTableName

This lead me to the problem. It was because of the below:

Originally using the spring session used their script which created a table called SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE...now we changed this table to add on more functionality and the name but on dev we still have it as a copy(should remove it). Out of habit I change the value there and committed when the table I was suppose to change was not that one at all but our custom table

Comment: Will mark this as answer as Antoniosss removed his post so can not mark.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is hibernate ***default String size is 255***; you can specify the String length using ***@Column*** annotation.

[image]

Let's assume our insert string length should be **1000** character length. We can solve it like below.

```
@Column(length = 1000)
private String data;
```